# How to handle shortcodes when using the JSON API

Tags: shortcode, javascript, json, plugin-json-api

I'm wrangling a little logic problem:

I'm making a single page WP theme which uses the JSON API for the content and Mustache style templates for the presentation... However, shortcodes? What would be the best way to handle these?

For example:

JSON result->template->DOM injection->trigger hijack for gallery/slideshow/whatever the shortcode is?

The above method feels a bit dirty as I'd have to either keep firing a parser to process the shortcodes or else I'd have to use JQuery.live (seriously dirty).

Can anyone think of a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add your own AJAX API for `do_shortcode`. Add this to a suitable location (i.e. `functions.php` or a plugin):

```
add_action('wp_ajax_doshortcode', 'ajax_doshortcode');
function doshortcode() {
  echo do_shortcode($_POST['text']);
  die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
```

And this to your Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  url : ajaxurl,
  data : { action : 'doshortcode', text : <text> },
  type : 'POST',
  error : function(req, stat, err) {...},
  success : function(data, stat, req) {...}
});
```

`ajaxurl` is defined on admin pages; see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side) for instructions for viewer-side applications.

Alternatively, you can set up such actions for all API functions you need, wrapping the original calls with `do_shortcode`.

Comment: The answer seems a bit vague. We tried the answer and could not get a solution. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Antonio I have no idea whether this still works in the same way, and I have not worked with WP for some time. Sorry. Maybe post a new question linking to this? The current herd of users might be able to help you more.